# xpath for the below code?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I am trying to find xpath for all `<fldChar fldCharType="end"/>` tags whose level is equal to the level of `<instrText xml:space="preserve">` . 
I tried `/word/r/instrText/preceding::fldChar` But it gives all the preceding `<fldChar fldCharType="end"/>` tag. I need only same leveled `<fldChar`.  please suggest me to sort it out.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <word>
        <r rsidRPr="00A35D44">
                                <rPr>
                                      <rFonts ascii="Times New Roman" eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
                                    </rPr>
                                <fldChar fldCharType="begin"/>
                              </r>
                          <r rsidRPr="00A35D44">
                                <rPr>
                                      <rFonts ascii="Times New Roman" eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
                                    </rPr>
                                <instrText xml:space="preserve"> XE “efficiency” </instrText>
                              </r>
                          <r rsidRPr="00A35D44">
                                <rPr>
                                      <rFonts ascii="Times New Roman" eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
                                    </rPr>
                                <fldChar fldCharType="end"/>
                          </r>
      <fldChar fldCharType="end"/>
                          <r rsidRPr="00A35D44">
                                <rPr>
                                      <rFonts ascii="Times New Roman" eastAsia="Times New Roman"/>
                                      <b val="0"/>
                                    </rPr>
                                <t>,</t>
                              </r>
                          <r rsidRPr="00A35D44">
                                <rPr>
                                      <rFonts eastAsia="Times New Roman" hAnsi="Arial Unicode MS"/>
                                    </rPr>
                                <instrText xml:space="preserve"> and equity</instrText>
                              </r>
                          </word>
```

Comment: There is also a `preceding-sibling` axis but I am not sure whether that meets your definition of same level.

Comment: I also tried preceding-sibling option but i didnt get result Mr.Martin Honnen

Comment: Can you tell us which elements in your sample you want to select?

Comment: <fldChar fldCharType="begin"/><fldChar fldCharType="end"/>

Comment: Does `//fldChar[@fldCharType="end"][some $it in //instrText[@xml:space = "preserve"] satisfies count(./ancestor::node()) eq count($it/ancestor::node())]` give you the elements you want? I am trying to understand your definition of "same level" by making XPath suggestions, you might need to elaborate on that condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Martin Honnen. I got what i want

Comment: @MartinHonnen, can you make that an answer, so that this question gets marked as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our interchange in the comments you are looking for the expression `//fldChar[@fldCharType="end"][some $it in //instrText[@xml:space = "preserve"] satisfies count(./ancestor::node()) eq count($it/ancestor::node())]`. Or a bit shorter `//fldChar[@fldCharType="end"][some $it in //instrText[@xml:space = "preserve"] satisfies count(ancestor::node()) eq count($it/ancestor::node())]`.